# how to get user document id while adding record to firebasefirestore in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am created a basic app for adding post where i need to store post id

I dont want to generate any id my own way, to know if there is a another way

here is my coding for adding post

```
IconButton(onPressed: () async {
                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").doc().set(
                        {
                          'message':txtpost.text,
                          'postby':FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
                          'posttime':Timestamp.now(),
                          'likes':[],
                          'postid':?????// here how to get current document id
                        });
                    print('Post Added Successfully...');
                    txtpost.clear();

                  }, icon: Icon(Icons.send))
```

Comment: i know there are some packages for id generator...but dont want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do it:

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final documentRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc();
          final documentId = documentRef.id;
              await documentRef.set(
                  {
                    'message':txtpost.text,
                    'postby':FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
                    'posttime':Timestamp.now(),
                    'likes':[],
                    'postid': documentId
                  });
              print('Post Added Successfully...');
              txtpost.clear();
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
```

Every document reference comes with an id. You can get this id and set it as the post id.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ID that is automatically generated when calling the function *doc* when no path is provided.

Therefore you could first get the reference of the doc and then store the post.

Here is how the code could look like:

```dart
    IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final docRef =
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc();
              final docId = docRef.id;
              docRef.set(
                {
                  'message': txtpost.text,
                  'postby': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
                  'posttime': Timestamp.now(),
                  'likes': [],
                  'postid': docId
                },
              );
              print('Post Added Successfully...');
              txtpost.clear();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.send),
          ),
```